# Symfony2: inject security context into model classes

Tags: symfony, service, hook, propel

I have propel classes that implement the preSave method. This is a hook where some fields can be automatically updated at each saving operation. This is needed in order to save the date of last update and the user of the last update.

The problem is that the model classes have no access to the service container, where I can get the user id (to set into the last update user field). Model classes cannot (at my knownledge) be declared as service, as these are kind of entities, instancied by propel itself and not by the service container.

The only solution I see is to have a "real" singleton (with a static instance) holding the user object, that I would instanciate during the bootstrap of the application, then any model class could access it.

Any better idea?

Comment: For Propel2: https://github.com/marcj/EventDispatcherBehavior. Use a listener, there you can attach/define other services as constructor arguments as usual.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same propel, the given bundle only adds the EventDispatchor behavior to Propel, which means that you can manage propel events in the same as Symfony does, but it is separated from the Symfony container (it seams it is using it own container).

But glorpen/propel-bundle is doing this job very well, you can really define service that listen to Propel events, using simple tags.